# How to delete all the content inside the tag in Sublime tex 2.0

Tags: html, sublimetext2

How to fast delete all the content inside a tag in sumblime?

```
<div>
...
Lot's of strings of code which I need to delete, but I don't want to looking for the closing tag.
...
</div>
```

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + A  , after this press DEL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Selection -> Expand Selection to Tag` should get you what you want. There should be a key binding in there that specifies the keyboard shortcut to do it.

Comment: For me the binding is `SHIFT + CTRL + A`